# Why I'm not getting products in react js context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm a beginner and I'm learning React JS. I am using react context. But I'm not getting `products` from the context.

**React context file:** `CartContext.jsx`

**I want to get "products" from "CartContext" to**: `Review.jsx`

Here my codes are given below.

**CartContext.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';

const CartContext = createContext();

export function CartProvider({ children }) {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const cartItems = item => {
    setProducts(prevState => [...prevState, item]);
  };

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{ products, cartItems }}>
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default CartContext;
```

**Review.jsx**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import './review.scss';
import CartContext from '../../contexts/CartContext';

const Review = () => {
  const { products } = useContext(CartContext);

  return (
    <div className="review container bg-light">
      <h1>Review</h1>
      {products.map(product => {
        <div>
          <h3>{product.name}</h3>
          <h5>{product.price}</h5>
        </div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Review;
```

**Products.jsx**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import './product.scss';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCartPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import CartContext from '../../contexts/CartContext';

const Product = props => {
  const { name, img, price, seller, stock } = props.product;

  const { cartItems } = useContext(CartContext);

  return (
    <div className="product">
      <div className="product-image">
        <img src={img} alt={name} />
      </div>
      <div className="product-details">
        <h5 className="product-name">{name}</h5>
        <small>
          from <span className="seller">{seller}</span>
        </small>
        <h3 className="price">${price}</h3>
        <p>Only {stock} items left in stock</p>
        <button
          className="main-button"
          onClick={() => cartItems(props.product)}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCartPlus} />
          <span className="add-to-cart">Add to cart</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Shop from './components/Shop/Shop';
import Review from './components/Review/Review.jsx';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CartProvider } from './contexts/CartContext';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <CartProvider>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Shop />} />
          <Route path="/shop" element={<Shop />} />
          <Route path="/review" element={<Review />} />
          <Route
            path="*"
            element={
              <main style={{ padding: '1rem' }}>
                <p>There's nothing here!</p>
              </main>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </CartProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Do you get any errors, and what does console logging this here give: const logThis = useContext(CartContext);

Comment: It looks like the 'review.jsx' is not connected with the CartContext.jsx file. I am tried to console.log(products) but it shows nothing in the console.